how to display an img in tkinter?
import customtkinter as ctk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import tkinter
window = ctk.CTk()
window.geometry("450x600")
Main_Frame = ctk.CTkFrame(window, 450,600,fg_color="green",corner_radius=0)
Main_Frame.pack()
Main_Canvas = ctk.CTkCanvas(Main_Frame, width=450, height=600,background="green",highlightthickness=0)
Main_Canvas.create_line(70,65,400,65,width=4)
Main_Canvas.create_line(90,75,380,75,width=4)
img= ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("main.png"))
Main_Canvas.create_image(10,10, anchor=NW,image=img)
Title = ctk.CTkLabel(Main_Canvas, text="تطبيق المسلم",font=("Arial",40))
Title.place(x=150, y=10)
Main_Canvas.pack()
window.mainloop()

im trying to display an img in the canvas and he kept give me this error :(.
Main_Canvas.create_image(10,10, anchor=NW,image=img) ^^ NameError: name 'NW' is not defined
pls help me to get rid of this probelm

if you use import tkinter (instead of from tkinter import *) then you need tkinter.NW (instead of NW). But import * is not preferred. You can also use string anchor="nw" (lowecase). BTW: try print( tkinter.NW ) and you get string "nw"

I don't know if I should write it because it is basic knowledge.
If you use import tkinter then you need tkinter.NW
If you would use import tkinter as tk then you would need tk.NW
If you would use  from tkinter import * (which is not preferred) then you would need NW
But you can always use string anchor="nw" (lowecase)
